# Meteor showing [object Object] after creating Meteor.Router.add()

Tags: javascript, meteor, router

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fqJW1X22Cg) to learn Meteor. After adding the first JS code, I'm getting [object Object] on my browser. I've followed everything as explained (except for some names that I have changed, but I haven't used any reserved words), but I cannot see anything else. This part is in the first 4 minutes. This is how my files look:

demonstration.js:

```
CalEvents = new Meteor.Collection('calevents');
Session.setDefault('editing_calevent', null);
Session.setDefault('showEditEvent', false);
Meteor.Router.add({
    '/':'home',
    '/calendar':'calendar'  
})
```

calendar.html:

```
<template name="calendar">
    <div id="calendar">
        Hello world! Now at calendar.
    </div>
</template>
```

home.html:

```
<template name="home">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <p>Manage your calendar</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>  
</template>
```

demonstration.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Calendar app</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{>menu}}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid"> 
            {{renderPage}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I suspect it has something to do with the Meteor.Router.add() line, because the little I did prior to adding this worked. I have tried changing the page to show on '/' to other pages that contained a simple text, but it didn't work.

Edit to add: I am working thru Nitrous.io and I installed Meteorite prior to adding the router package.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I have searched in here and on Google but I haven't been able to find any answer to this question. If there is one, kindly point me to the right address.

Comment: Meteor Router is deprecated. Try using Iron Router: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router

Comment: What's your Meteor version? You can check in `/.meteor/release` file. I'd suppose the old router is not compatible with Meteor 0.8.0.

Comment: Geoffrey: I don't know how to give you reputation points :((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of examples that use Meteor prior to version 0.8 will not work, so make sure you check out a recently updated example, like those on [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/).

In this case, [router has been fixed to support Meteor 0.8](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/pull/142) and your example will work by replacing `{{renderPage}}` with `{{> renderPage}}`. However, the rest of the example probably won't work, and as others have mentioned, router has been deprecated for [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Geoffrey and Hubert for your answers. I have the latest Meteor version a few days ago.

I have another problem, but I think I'll open another thread, since I consider this one answered.