# Meteor and fullcalendar package: I can't add events to my calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, meteor, fullcalendar

As explained in my [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114107/meteor-showing-object-object-after-creating-meteor-router-add?noredirect=1), I'm following a Meteor tutorial and learning to do a calendar app.

Edit: corrected a few mistakes, plus I made a separate file for the collection called calevents.js, which is placed in a collections folder.

I can add events, but the pop-up window won't show so I can't give them a new name. As this doesn't happen, the new event won't show either. For me to see the events, I have to refresh manually. On edit: I can rename the event but it won't change when I click on Save.

Here is my code so far:

demonstration.js:

```
    Session.setDefault('editingCalEvent', null);
Session.setDefault('showEditEvent', false);
Session.setDefault('lastMod', null);

Router.map(function () {
      this.route('home', {
        path: '/'
      });
      this.route('calendar', {
        path: '/calendar'
      });
});

Template.calendar.showEditEvent = function() {
  return Session.get('showEditEvent');
}

Template.editevent.evt = function() {
  var calEvent =  CalEvents.findOne({_id:Session.get('editingCalEvent')});
  return calEvent;
}

Template.editevent.events({
    'click .save': function() {
    console.log("update 123, ¿pasó por aquí?");
        updateCalEvent(Session.get('editingCalEvent'), $("#title").val());
    Session.set('editingCalEvent', null);
        Session.set('showEditEvent',false);
        Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
    }
})

Template.calendar.rendered = function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            dayClick:function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
         //console.log("insertando...", date);
         CalEvents.insert({title: 'New Event', start: date, end: date});
         Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
            },

            eventClick:function(calEvent,jsEvent,view) {
                 Session.set('editingCalEvent', calEvent.id);
         Session.set('showEditEvent', true);
            },

      eventDrop:function(calEvent) {
                 CalEvents.update(calEvent.id, {$set: {start:calEvent.start,end:calEvent.end}});
                 Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
            },

            events: function(start, end, callback) {
         var events = [];
         calEvents = CalEvents.find();
         calEvents.forEach(function(evt) {
           events.push({
             id: evt._id,
             title: evt.title,
             start: evt.start,
             end: evt.end
           });
         });
         callback(events);
             },
       editable:true
         });
}

Template.calendar.lastMod = function() {
    return Session.get('lastMod');
}

var updateCalEvent = function(id, title) {
    CalEvents.update(id, {$set: {title:title}});
      return true;
}
```

calendar.html:

```
    <template name="calendar">
    {{#if showEditEvent}}
      {{ >editevent}}
    {{/if}}
  <input type="hidden" name="lastMod" value="{{lastMod}}" id="lastMod">
  <div id="calendar">

  </div>
</template>

<template name="editevent">
  <div id="example" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
      <h3>Edit event</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <label for="title">Event:</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{{evt.title}}">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success save">Save</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

home.html:

```
<template name="home">
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <h1>Calendar app</h1>
    <p>Manage your calendar</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

demonstration.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Calendar app</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{>menu}}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid"> 
            {{renderPage}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have also downloaded the code from the website given on the tutorial, uploaded it to my Nitrous box, but it doesn't work either. At first I thought that it was something about Nitrous, but it could be something about the Meteor version and unfortunately I don't know enough to find the problem.

The other threads about something related to fullcalendar don't address my problem, but if you think they do, please point me in the right direction. I have also looked at the API of the package, but I'm clueless. 
Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add events that correspond to the appropriate template.

For example:

```
Template.calendar.events({
  'click .css-class-name': function(){
     //do something on click
     console.log("click event fired");
   },
});
```

This will trigger an event on click of any HTML element with a class = "css-class-name", but only for elements within the calendar template.

If you're trying to trigger an event in the "editevent" template, then you would need to make sure you do:

```
Template.editevent.events({
  'click .css-class-name': function(){
     //do something on click
     console.log("click event fired");
   },
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I get errors using your suggestions :( no matter where I put this in the demonstration.js.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here to get it up and running. First of all the `editevent` template is never used. You should render it using the `{{> editevent}}` tag in the appropriate place in the HTML (I assume that the `calendar` template would be a suitable place).

Also, you are now initiating the `fullCalendar` package in your `Template.calendar.rendered` function. That's great. But you must also catch the click events to update the events. Here's how they do it in the tutorial source code:

```
Template.editEvent.events({
    'click .save':function(evt,tmpl){
        updateCalEvent(Session.get('editing_calevent'),tmpl.find('.title').value);
        Session.set('editing_event',null);
        Session.set('showEditEvent',false);
        Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
    }
})
```

The code above would catch all click events in the `editEvents` template on any element with the class `save`.

You are also referencing `evt` in your template, but that is not defined in your JavaScript code. This is the corresponding code from the tutorial to populate `evt`.

```
Template.editEvent.evt = function(){
    var calEvent = CalEvents.findOne({_id:Session.get('editing_calevent')});
    return calEvent
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you already resolve this issue? If yes, please let us know what the cause exactly was?

My guess is, that this has little to do with the editevent.
I think it has to do with the insert command.
Trying to reproduce your case, I encountered an error: "insert failed: method not found".
So I am guessing your insert is not working.

Probably, you only have declared the collection in the client side code.
So, if you add a server.js file and add to that:

`CalEvents = new Meteor.Collection('calevents');`

Than your collection will be declared to the server side as well, allowing the server to process it.

Best regards,

Comment: Hi @user2207415, I found some errors on my code but the problem still persists. I will update the code in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the problem could be that you are trying to run Bootstrap-2 coding (that's what is in the tutorial!) where you have (maybe) installed Bootstrap-3 on your Meteor application.

The modal in the EditEvent template in that case won't work since it's coding has changed completely in Bootstrap-3.

Check what version of Bootstrap you have installed in your application by maneuvering to it in the console and run: meteor list --using

You can eliminate the cause of your problem in various ways. If you put a simple text in your template EditEvent above the dialog, you can see if this shows on clicking an event. You then know, that the problem lies in the modal.

Comment: I'm running the latest version of Bootstrap (and the other packages as well). I did discover that I didn't install jQuery UI and when I did that, I got the EditEvent template popping up, but if I change the name of the event, it won't save it.

Also, I can't get any pop-up window to insert and name any event.

Comment: I can confirm that. It won't save here as well. I do have the modal pop-up, and I can see the title is in there, but on clicking the save button it will not update the record. In the Chrome console I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" and then it points to "updateCalEvent(Session.get('editing_calevent'),tmpl.find('.title').value);" more specifically to the '.title'. It seems that this does not get passed in here. It does get to the function however, so the function does execute on clicking the save button. It just does not get the value passed to title.

Comment: That's odd. I don't get any errors or warnings. Now there's a new development (I haven't had time to do anything new) and it saves the name but for you to see it, you have to refresh manually. GRRRR.

Comment: BTW can you insert at all and/or do you have to refresh manually?

Comment: As the developer of the tutorial already responded below, I feel a bit uncomfortable commenting here, but you are missing the "class="title" tag in the input HTML command on the EditEvent template page. You have: <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{{evt.title}}"> should be changed into: <input type="text" name="title" class="title" id="title" value="{{evt.title}}">. Also, if you are running Bootstrap 3, than your modal is not configured correctly. You need content tags etc etc. Check the modal requirements in the bootstrap documentation on release 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
    updateCalEvent(Session.get('editingCalEvent'), $("#title").val());
To...
    updateCalEvent(Session.get('editingCalEvent'), tmpl.find('#title').value);

Comment: I get this error "ReferenceError: tmpl is not defined"

Comment: 'click .save': function(evt,tmpl) {   ----sorry, the function needs to pass the tmpl